# Не работает конкатенация из свойством обьекта

Tags: php

`$model_data` - класс, который содержит 4 свойства: code1,..,code4
Данный код вызывает ошибку `Не определено свойство "MyClass.code"`:

```
for($i = 0; $i++ < 4;){
     echo $model_data->code.$i;
}
```

Можно конечно переписать таким образом:

```
for($i = 0; $i++ < 4;){
     <? $code='code'.$i?>
     <? echo $model_data->$code; ?>
}
```

Но все же интересует почему в 1-ом варианте не срабатывает конкатенация?

Comment: в первом вначале вызываете свойство, затем склеиваете, во втором, вначале склеиваете затем вызываете. вариант: `$model_data->{'code'.$i}`

Comment: @Bookin спасибо, помогло